# How can I use d3.select(this) if I'm importing the mouseover function from another script?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I'm defining the function within the event listener, it works perfectly as shown below

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'orange')
    ....
})
```

But it stops working when I'm importing the function from a `module.js` file. I believe it has something to do with `this` refering to something else when used in an imported function.

`script.js`

```
.on('mouseover', utils.mouseOverFunction})
```

`utils.js`

```
export function mouseOverFunction(){
    d3.select(this)..... // Does not work anymore
}
```

How would I be able to rectify this?

SOLUTION: I've managed to get it working with the following code

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){utils.mouseOverFunction(total, d, this)})
// total is a parameter I'm using in the function
// d is the datapoint being passed through in the data join
// `this` - is the context that is being passed through
```

Comment: You can bind it: `el.on('mouseover', utils.mouseOverFunction.bind(el) })` or pass it: `.on('mouseover', function () { utils.mouseOverFunction(this); })` and add a parameter to the function.

Comment: Great! Does this mean if I'm chaining methods prior, I would have to break the chain and reference the selection with variable `el`?